# Playing more than 1 song using AVAudio player issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Using `AVAudioPlayer` we can play more than 1 song in a loop using this method:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

to play the next song. But is it possible to identify the `AVAudioPlayer` instance since at a single time there are many `AVAudioPlayer` playing separate playlist in a app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `player` (first argument) from

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

is the `AVAudioPlayer`, that you are looking for.

So you can check it:

```
if ([player isEqual:self.audioPlayer1])
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: if i have more than 1 avaudio player instance then how can i identify which instance is being called.

Comment: yeah thanks ..but got a weird issue on allocating a new  avaudio player instance  in audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying.it did not play the song unless i put that refernce into the global avaudio player which i have defined.